# Jumping between functions (pascal)

Tags: vim

I know that Vim has "[[" and "]]" shortcuts to move between functions. But how can I add this functionality not only for C but for Pascal syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some filetypes redefine the built-in `]]` mappings to jump to the beginning of the next function. For example, have a look `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/vim.vim`:

```
" Move around functions.
nnoremap <silent><buffer> [[ m':call search('^\s*fu\%[nction]\>', "bW")<CR>
vetlocal foldmethod< foldtext< foldexpr< | delcommand FoldToggle oremap <silent><buffer> [[ m':<C-U>exe "normal! gv"<Bar>call search('^\s*fu\%[nction]\>', "bW")<CR>
```

You can define similar mappings (e.g. to the `begin` / `end` keywords) in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/pascal.vim`.

---

If you want a comfortable plugin that makes it easy to setup those mappings, supports [count], and also offers text objects to select an entire function, have a look at my [CountJump plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3130).
There's even an example about Pascal in its help:

```
:call CountJump#Motion#MakeBracketMotion('<buffer>', '', '', '\c^begin\n\zs', '\c^.*\nend', 0)
```